# How to upload documents to AWS CloudSearch with Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudsearch

So I'm not sure how to point to the correct domain with:

```
boto3.client('cloudsearchdomain').upload_documents(file, type)
```

The [documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudsearchdomain.html) says to configure the domains with CloudSearch `DescribeDomains` actions.

However, the [documentation for CloudSearch](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudsearch.html#CloudSearch.Client.describe_domains) only lists a method, `describe_domains`, which merely lists the domains, info etc.

How do I point to the correct domain to upload documents to CloudSearch?

Answer (score 7):

when initializing the client, use the kwarg `endpoint_url` ->

```
boto3.client('cloudsearchdomain', endpoint_url="http://search.example.cloudsearch.aws")
```

Comment: Note importantly that while boto3.client('cloudsearch').describe_domains() will give you the endpoint, you need to add 'http://' to it or it will just complain that it doesn't exist.